# Manipulate number inside diamond shape on Java

Tags: java, console

picture of result that i want
:

[image: diamonds]

I want to print out diamond shape like in the picture in the link. The user will first need to input either 0,1 and 2 only. If user enter 0 the result will be on the left one in the picture. If user enter 1 the result will be same as the middle one and if user enter 2, result like the right one.

From what I understand I need to do the half part of the diamond first. There will be the outer loop to determine the row. First inner loop to create the whitespaces. Second, inner loop for the number input by user. Lastly make another half  of the diamond, just make it decrement instead.

The problem is I don't understand how to manipulate the number like in the result in the picture.

Can someone give some hint on what should I do. I don't want the code. Maybe, just a bit explanation on what i should know first to do this

Comment: I'd suggest you try it and show some code. Further, I'd suggest doing it in 3 steps: 1) try to build pattern 1, i.e. all 0. 2) Think about how the numbers change for pattern 2: the further from the center, the larger they get. Once you've solved no. 1 this should be easy to add. 3) Multiply the numbers by user input, i.e. 0, 1 or 2. That gives 0,4,8 or 0,3,6 etc.

Comment: Another hint: as Thomas said, really begin with *coding*. It is part of the process to stare at it for hours sometimes, making tons of experiments that lead nowhere. That is how you learn programming. The other part is: looking at your expected output and identifying **patterns**.  And of course, you have to clarify your requirements. What happens when you enter a number like 5, 6, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: it can be done with 2 for loops: one for row number (0 to 8 inclusive) and one for column number (also 0 to 8 inclusive).

Start creating a pattern like:

```
432101234
432101234
...
```

extended to 9 lines (I just did't want to make it too big). Basically some calculation using just the column number like in `4 - col` (not complete, missing handling of negative results - intentionally left for the reader to do).

Then think of a condition using row and column number to eliminate the first corner (something like `col < 4-row`). In that case print a space instead of the digit:

```
    01234
   101234
  2101234
 32101234
432101234
432101234
432101234
432101234
432101234
```

do similar for the other three corners.

And, at last, multiply each digit by the input value (0, 1 or 2).

---

*"what i should know first"*

- `for` loops
- `if` statements or conditional operator (`? :`)
- comparing numbers and some maths (`col < 4 - row`)
- output `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()`)
- user input using the `main` argument(s) or reading standard input (depending on how that should be done)